# Bootstrap/JQuery - Blur and Make Unclickable Everything but Div

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Similar to how JQuery UI has the dialog box where everything behind it is blurred and not clickable if you set `modal` to `true`.  Meaning that the user can't venture and click elsewhere before answering/confirming the message displayed.  Is it possible to do this using Bootstrap and JQuery?  I've searched similar problems and the solutions usually just point to other plugins, there's got to be a way to hard code this, right?

Using $.notify for the Bootstrap messages.  Using $('*div*'.dialog({*etc.*}) for the loading screens. I've checked the options for the Bootstrap and there isn't one for them unlike with the JQuery.  The messages are for delete confirmations.

I've tried:

```
$("#confdelete").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

An answer I saw in other threads.  And I can't combine the two.  I pretty much want to take how it's doing it in the dialog and bring it into the Bootstrap.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options set `backdrop` to static to not dismiss the modal on off click

Comment: I should have specified, I'm using this: http://bootstrap-growl.remabledesigns.com/  I can't switch, but thanks!  That would have solved my problem from the start if it was the same.